# Probability of different people being born on the same day of the week

Tags: probability

What is the chance that at least two people were born on the same day of the week if there are 3 people in the room?

I know how to get the answer which is 19/49 when considering all 3 people **not being born on the same day**. However, when I try to calculate the answer directly I seem to get it wrong.

Considering exactly 2 people being born on the same day I get 1*1/7*6/7. And then, exactly 3 people is 1*1/7*1/7. Thus, the total is 6/49 + 1/49 = 7/49. This must be something fairly simple, but I was just wondering where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Just compute the probability that no two are born on the same day...$7$ choices for the first, $6$ for the next, $5$ for the last.  Thus $\frac {7\times 6\times 5}{7^3}$.  Your answer is one minus this.

Comment: The only mistake you made is that you need to multiply your first expression by $3$ as there are three choices for the odd man out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only mistake you have committed is that you have not included the combinations while calculation of 2 were born on the same day
If you name the persons A, B ,C
Since the two of them may be
A B,
B C,
C A
Therefore you must also multiply it by a factor of 3

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to arrive at the answer $P(\text{at least two people on same day of week}) = 1 - P(\text{all people on different days of the week}) = 1 - \frac{7 * 6 * 5}{7 * 7 * 7} = 1 - \frac{30}{49} = \frac{19}{49}$.

The main thing there is $P(\text{all people on different days of the week}) = \frac{\text{no of ways to assign three different birthdays to three guys}}{\text{total no of ways to assign three birthdays to three guys}}$.

In your calculation, you are missing some cases. Exactly two people born of the same day is $7 * \frac{1}{7} *\frac{1}{7} * \frac{6}{7} * 3$. And like you said, all three people on one day is $7 * \frac{1}{7} * \frac{1}{7}$.

Your calculation is wrong here:

> Considering exactly 2 people being born on the same day I get
>   1*1/7*6/7

You must multiply by 3 because you can choose any of the three guys to not have the identical birthday.